# XML Databinding Issue in ASP

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, data-binding

I am reading Server Name and port Number from an XML file and assigning to a Dropdown list box.

XML InPUT:

Server_Name: DEV1
 Porrt:001
 Server_Name: DEV2
 Porrt:002
 Server_Name: DEV3
 Porrt:003
 Server_Name: DEV4
 Porrt:001

Server_Name is mapped to Text field of Dropdown
Port is mapped to Value field of Dropdown.

The issue here is that If I choose DEV4, it is getting connected to DEV2.
Since these two shares the same port number , I couldnt select/connect to DEV4.

"Dropdown_ServerName" is the dropdownlist box

```
using (DataSet dssrc = new DataSet())
            {



                    dssrc.ReadXML(Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
                    ["XMLName"].ToString()));  
                    Dropdown_ServerName.DataSource = dssrc.Tables[0];
                    Dropdown_ServerName.DataTextField = "Server_Name";
                    Dropdown_ServerName.DataValueField = "Port";
                    Dropdown_ServerName.DataValueField.ToString();
                    Dropdown_ServerName.DataBind();

                }
```

Above is the Snippet for Databinding to Dropdown.
Can  anyone say how can I fix the issue? Or how the Data binding actually happend if two entities share the same value for datafield and different value for Datatextfield of a dropdown?.

Thanks
Nandha

Comment: Check Device Manager and check names of devices connected to you PC.  Are there devices Serial Ports or some sort of USB device?  USB devices don't always come up in same configuration.  You may need to reassign the devices from device manager.

Comment: I am reading the port numbers from an XML file.

Comment: Still the XML could be wrong.  Verify in device manager that the port number is correct.  USB devices can randomly change numbers.